# UNIX timestamp comparison

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using fallowing schema for my database to store messaging threads.

```
CREATE TABLE threads(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    date_sent_or_received INTEGER, 
    read INTEGER, 
    count INTEGER, 
    body TEXT, 
    address TEXT, 
    error_code INTEGER);
```

I have the fallowing trigger that gets activated whenever I insert values into a SMS table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_thread_id AFTER INSERT ON sms
WHEN
0 <> (select count() from threads
      where length(address)>=length(new.address)
        and substr(address, length(address)-length(new.address)+1) like new.address)
BEGIN
UPDATE threads SET
    address = new. address
where substr(address, length(address)-length(new.address)+1) like new.address;

UPDATE threads SET
    date_sent_or_received=new.date_sent_or_received,
    read = new.read,
    body = new.body 
where date_sent_or_received<=new.date_sent_or_received
  and address like new.address;

UPDATE sms SET
    thread_id= (select _id from threads
                where address like new.address)
where _id = new._id;

UPDATE threads SET
    count = (select count() from sms 
             where thread_id=(select _id from threads 
                              where address like new.address))
where address like new.address;

END;
```

I am encountering problem statement where I am trying to change content of thread only when it is older than the newer one. It goes like this.

```
UPDATE threads SET
    date_sent_or_received=new.date_sent_or_received,
    read = new.read,
    body = new.body 
where date_sent_or_received<=new.date_sent_or_received
  and address like new.address;
```

However, it doesn't works. Content of the table remains same even when newly inserted row is larger in timestamp, this trigger updates the address according to newly added row.

I am storing seconds in Integer. 
Any ideas where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution to your question. But since your question is regarding queries, and if you are doing these operations in SQLite, please test your SQL statements in SQliteBrowser or SQLite manager. There you can understand how the database is reacting to your statements.